# Limit constructor scope in nested struct

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have an incredibly contrived class defined as follows:

```
class Outer {
public:
    struct Inner {
        Inner(int innerValue) : foo(innerValue) {};
        int foo;
    };

    Outer(int innerValue) : _inner(innerValue) {};

    const Inner& getInner() const {
        return _inner;
    };

private:
    Inner _inner;
};
```

I want `Outer` to be the only class capable of constructing an instance of `Inner`, but in such a way that other classes/functions can access `_inner.foo` when passed a reference to `_inner` through `Outer::getInner()`. Is this possible? Is there a better way of achieving equivalent functionality?

Comment: Could you make the constructor private and then make `Outer` a friend of `Inner`? I don't have time to test that idea at the moment.

Comment: @JosephMansfield - turns out we can! See leemes' answer below. They posted a second solution, too, which I think is rather novel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm aware of two solutions to such a problem which I'd like to demonstrate and compare.

**Solution 1 (`friend`):**

Using the `friend` keyword, you can allow another class to access your private functions. (Use carefully.)

You can make the constructor of `Inner` private, but make `Outer` a friend of `Inner`. Note that not only the constructor but any private method of `Inner` can be called by `Outer`.

```
class Outer {
public:
    class Inner {
        friend class Outer;     // <<---- friend

        // private to Inner but also callable by Outer (because it's a friend):
        Inner(int innerValue) : foo(innerValue) {};

    public:
        // (add public methods here)
        int foo;
    };

    Outer(int innerValue) : _inner(innerValue) {};

    const Inner& getInner() const {
        return _inner;
    };

private:
    Inner _inner;
};
```

**Solution 2 (access keys):**

A different approach without `friend` but slightly more complex is to give the constructor a parameter which only `Outer` is able to construct (like a "key"). The constructor is then public, but other classes will not be able to call it since they can't provide the arguments required to do so:

```
class Outer {
    // Our dummy struct which is only constructible by Outer:
    struct ConstructInnerKey {
        // Empty
    };

public:
    struct Inner {
        Inner(int innerValue, Outer::ConstructInnerKey) : foo(innerValue) {};
        //                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //                a key is required (but not used)
        //                to construct an instance of Inner

        // (add public methods here)
        int foo;
    };

    Outer(int innerValue) : _inner(innerValue, Outer::ConstructInnerKey()) {};
    //                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                                      make a key and pass it to Inner

    const Inner& getInner() const {
        return _inner;
    };

private:
    Inner _inner;
};
```

Note that while this looks like it adds a performance overhead, this is not the case. Everything is optimized away and only serves for catching access violations during compilation as you'd like to.

**Comparison:**

Solution 2 has the advantage that `Inner` only grants `Outer` to access the constructor. So as long as you want to have "truly" private functions in `Inner` (not even accessible by `Outer`), this is a good solution. But solution 1 is a lot easier to write and understand (quick and dirty, so to speak).

Comment: Ah, duh! That will probably work for me - giving this a less contrived attempt right now...

Comment: @Nate I added an alternative approach :)

Comment: Sneaky. In my use-case the friend version will work fine, as no other private functions exist in Inner - I'll definitely keep the access key solution in mind for future problems, though. Thanks!